NiFi How can I determine that everything from the start of the flow has processed?
Is there any way to determine that all flowfiles have completed in a flow?
Scenario:

NiFi receives an Oracle .dmp file
NiFi calls a script to process the .dmp file
NiFi then queries the database for its records
NiFi has dozens of other processors that evaluate, split, merge, push & pull data from the database

So you cannot go by the x records as a count because I can start with 100 records but process 80k flowfiles.
Is there a way to determine at the end of the flow that the flowfile it just got is actually the last one that is in the flow?
